# Using VBA can I set a worksheet to fit one page and use up the entire page

Tags: excel, vba, printing

I have an application that create a report (worksheet) intended to be printed.

Depending on which user generates the report, Excel has the potential to determine different page printing areas.

I tried to solve this using

```
reportSheet.PageSetup.printArea = "A1:" & PageCorner
reportSheet.PageSetup.Zoom = False
reportSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 1
reportSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
```

The problem I am now facing is that I'm now getting a margin on the right side of the print preview page. After testing (increasing the row height of each row) I've determine that this is caused by Excel proportionally shrinking both the height and width until it all fits on one page.

Is there a way to get Excel to not proportionally shrink the report but to shrink or stretch the width and height independently so that the full page is used (doubtful)?

If no, I plan to create a script to choose a width for a column(s) that would accomplish this and I'm wondering if anyone has tackled this before and could help me by explaining how you accomplished this?

Reason: The report has an image which needs to go all the way to the end of the right side of the page when printed. Currently there is a white margin that appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no simple way to tell Excel to stretch or shrink the columns to fit the width of the page after the fit to page height was applied in this case.

For the VBA solution, you could use something like this if you want the stretching/shrinking to be proportional by column width:

```
reportSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:" & PageCorner
reportSheet.PageSetup.Zoom = False
reportSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 1
reportSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1

Dim pa As Range
Set pa = reportSheet.Range("Print_Area")


Dim HeightToWidth As Double

Select Case reportSheet.PageSetup.PaperSize

    Case Is = xlPaperLetter: HeightToWidth = 8.5 / 11
    Case Is = xlPaperLegal:  HeightToWidth = 8.5 / 14
    Case Is = xlPaperA4:     HeightToWidth = 210 / 297

End Select

Dim MultFactor As Double
MultFactor = pa.Height * HeightToWidth / pa.Width

Dim col As Range
For Each col In pa.Columns
    col.ColumnWidth = col.ColumnWidth * MultFactor
Next
```

**EDIT:**

After some more testing on my end, it seems like Excel doesn't actually use the whole page even when all margins are set to zero, so there is a little discrepancy and I need to adjust for that. I've noticed that with the letter format, I get the best result if I multiply MultFactor by 0.9 before applying it to the columns (but that might differ for you).

```
col.ColumnWidth = col.ColumnWidth * MultFactor * 0.9
```